# Rails3 loading model schema on every request

Tags: performance, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scalability

I am running my app on heroku. It is a database intensive app and uses around 150 tables. Hence it is very slow.

I have configured newrelic to scale it and figure out the issue.
Then I came to know that rails is firing an extra query for each used model to load it's schema on every request.

for example

```
SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
WHERE a.attrelid = '"sub_regions"'::regclass
AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Is there any way , I can prevent rails to load model's schema on every request?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you check that config.cache_classes = true in the production.rb file ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can choose what columns you want to load with ActiveRecord's `select`.

See para `2.5 Selecting Specific Fields`, [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: I dont think the question is about selcting the attributes in your query . 
I am facing the exact same problem ... it seems likes rails is firing these queries in every request to "load the Models" . Querying the models comes after that . 
I thought that rails loads models in every request only in the development mode, but seems like it is loading the models everytime in production mode as well .